# Is my proof that the Sharkovsky Ordering is a total ordering, correct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, dynamical-systems, natural-numbers, well-orders

The [Sharkovsky ordering](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Sharkovsky_ordering) is an ordering of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, where

$3$  $\prec$   $5 $      $\prec$      $7 $     $\prec$  $9$      $\prec$   ... 
$2*3$  $\prec$  $2*5$   $\prec$      $2*7$     $\prec$  $2*9$      $\prec$  ...
...
$2^n*3$  $\prec$  $2^n*5$   $\prec$ $2^n*7$  $\prec$  $2^n*9$  $\prec$  ...
...
... $2^n$  $\prec$  ...     $\prec$  $2^3$      $\prec$  $2^2$      $\prec$  $2$  $\prec$  $1$

The ordering starts with all odd numbers, except for one, in increasing order, followed by two times the odds, $2^2$ times the odds, $2^3$ times the odds and so one. Finally the powers of two are listed last in decreasing order.

**I know what to prove that this order is a total ordering.** Thus, I need to show

1. Antisymmetry: If $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$ then $a=b$
2. Transitivity: If $a \leq b$ and $b \leq c$ then $a \leq c$
3. Connexity: $a\leq b$ or $b \leq a$

I came up with the following mapping from the Sharkovsky ordering to the natural numbers:
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  P =
    \begin{cases}
      \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 & \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
      (r,p) & \rightarrow 2^r \cdot (2p+1)
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

As this function is bijective, each natural number appears exactly once in the Sharkovsky ordering.

See [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3917583/118539) below for attempt at proof.

Comment: It's not quite enough, but it's a good start. Can you describe when $P(r,p)\le P(r',p')$ in terms of $r$ and $p$?

Comment: I tried, by looking at three different cases. 1: $p' \neq 0$, which implies $r < r'$ or ($r=r'$ and $p < p'$). case 2: $p' = 0$ and $p \neq 0$, case 3: $p = p' = 0$. I do not know how to put my results for these cases together into one.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply define the relation $\prec$ carefully and then use the definition to show that $\preceq$ is a linear order. Specifically,

$$\begin{align*}
2^r(2k+1)\prec 2^s(2\ell+1)\text{ iff }&r<s\text{ and }k\ne 0\ne\ell,\text{ or}\\
&r=s\text{ and }0<k<\ell,\text{ or}\\
&r>s\text{ and }k=\ell=0,\text{ or}\\
&k>0\text{ and }\ell=0\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: So, for the case of Antisymmetry I would than have to show that $2^r(2k+1) \prec 2^s(2l+1) $ and $2^s(2l+1) \prec 2^r(2k+1)$ is logically equivallent to $2^r(2k+1) = 2^s(2l+1)$?

Comment: @Linchen: Yes (except that you’d be looking at $\preceq$ rather than the strict order $\prec$).

Comment: thanks! yeah, I couldn't find the command for that sign. I'm am obviously very new to this side, so please parden my question, but is it okay if I try to answer my own question in this thread so other people can double check?

Comment: @Linchen: The code for $\preceq$ is `\preceq`. Yes, that’s entirely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

**Is my proof correct?**

**1. Antisymmetry**

First, $$2^r (2k+1) \preceq 2^s (2l+1)   \text{(1)}$$
$\text{ if } r < s \text{ and } k \neq 0 \neq l, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } r = s \text{ and } 0 < k < l, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } r > s \text{ and } k = l = 0, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } k > 0 \text{ and } l = 0,\text{or}$
$\text{ if } r = s \text{ and } k = l,$

Second, $$2^s (2l+1) \preceq 2^r (2k+1)   \text{(2)}$$
$\text{ if } s < r \text{ and } l \neq 0 \neq k, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } r = s \text{ and } 0 < l < k, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } s > r \text{ and } l = k = 0, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } l > 0 \text{ and } k = 0,\text{or}$
$\text{ if } r = s \text{ and } k = l,$

Thus, if both (1) and (2) are true, $r = s$ and $k = l$, because all other options lead to contradictions. Hence $2^r (2k+1) = 2^s (2l+1)$, which implys Antisymmetry.

**2. Transitivity**

First, $$2^r (2k+1) \preceq 2^s (2l+1)   \text{(1)}$$
$\text{ if } r < s \text{ and } k \neq 0 \neq l, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } r = s \text{ and } 0 < k < l, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } r > s \text{ and } k = l = 0, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } k > 0 \text{ and } l = 0,\text{or}$
$\text{ if } r = s \text{ and } k = l,$

Second, $$2^s (2l+1) \preceq 2^t (2m+1)   \text{(2)}$$
$\text{ if } s < t \text{ and } l \neq 0 \neq m, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } t = s \text{ and } 0 < l < m, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } s > t \text{ and } l = m = 0, \text{or}$
$\text{ if } l > 0 \text{ and } m = 0,\text{or}$
$\text{ if } t = s \text{ and } m = l,$

Than,
$r<s<t$ and $k \neq 0 \neq l \neq 0 \neq m \Rightarrow r<t$ and $k \neq 0 \neq m$
$r = s = t$ and $0 < k < l<m$ $\Rightarrow r = t$ and $0 < k < m$
$r > s > t$ and $k = l = m = 0$ $\Rightarrow r > t$ and $m = 0$
$r = s = t$ and $k = l = m$ $\Rightarrow r = t$ and $k = m$

Hence,  $2^r (2k+1) \preceq 2^t (2m+1)$.